# What is numerical value of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given 26 constants labelled A to Z, let $A = 1$.

The rest of the constants have values that are equal to the position of that letter in the alphabet, raised to the power of the previous constant, so:

- $A = 1$
- $B$ (the letter in the second position) $= 2^A = 2^1 = 2$
- $C$ (the letter in the third position) $= 3^B = 3^2 = 9$
- etc.

Find the exact numerical value for this expression:

$(N-A) * (N-B) * (N-C) * ... * (N-Y) * (N-Z)$

Comment: What do you mean with $N$? If it is a letter, then $0$

Comment: Well... the expression includes (N-N), does it not?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of having an answer: the expression is multiplied by the term $(N-N)$, which is zero, so the whole thing evaluates to zero.

Answer (score 0):

This actually appears on Math Overflow under the question "Math Puzzles for Dinner."

[Here is the link.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29323/math-puzzles-for-dinner/29326#29326)

There is an answer there too, but my hint is what happens around the letter $M$ in the product?